# How to change Security zone setting of IE Edge browser in windows 10 for selenium webdriver automation

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am doing selenium web driver automation on windows 10 IE Edge browser. I can able to launch IE Edge browser but command prompt which is launched for Microsoft driver is running in front and "IE Edge" browser window running backside of that hence some test are failing due to such behavior in IE Edge.

So i want to try with changing primary setting of IE Edge for selenium web driver like changing Security zone setting at same level and all other required setting needed for selenium web driver.

Please any help in IE edge is greatly appreciated.

**Note**: What i think is the existing test which are running on IE 11 with selenium web driver. Those same tests are not working in IE Edge with selenium web driver. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Edge configurations are not 100% same as others. It requires additional installation in order the WebDriver to talk to the browser. I have not personally tested/used it yet. But, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044912/is-there-a-selenium-webdriver-available-for-the-microsoft-edge-browser) answer. 
According to JimEvans answer, you must upgrade the Selenium bindings to 2.47 since this release has necessary changes.

Note: Of course not all API will work with edge browser. The link above answers most of common questions you may have.

Comment: I have added 2.47.0 bindings for C# and also installed "Microsoft Webdriver but what i think is "Full support" for selenium webdriver automation is not implemented in IE Edge. What i observed is -"Switch to Window" is not happening on IE Edge and the same test is passing on IE 11. We can not set focus on IEEdge browser ..as default focus is went on "Microsoft Webdriver" command screen.                                      EdgeOptions options = new EdgeOptions();
                    options.RequireWindowFocus = true;
                    options.EnsureCleanSession = true;

Comment: @simond I have mentioned that in my answer. Not all the API are available yet. See [this](http://dev.modern.ie/platform/status/webdriver/details/)

Comment: Can you please let me know when should we get fully implemented WebDriver for IE Edge on windows 10(Is there any estimated date by Microsoft) , do we have nay announcement for that.