# Microsoft Edge not stay open when run by Microsoft WebDriver

Tags: c#, webdriver

My OS Build: 16299.309 so
I download MS WebDriver, ver. 5.16299 release: 16299, from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

My `SetEdgeDriver()` method in C#:

```
private IWebDriver SetEdgeDriver()
    {
        try
        {
            var path = @"C:\FolderWhereMSWebDriverExeFile ";
            var option = new EdgeOptions();

            option.PageLoadStrategy = PageLoadStrategy.Normal;                
            return new EdgeDriver(path, option);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }
    }
```

When the unit test is executed, Edge browser opens briefly then it closes with an error saying "`Unexpected error. Unknown error`"

The test is just about going to Google search site and works fine with Chrome. 

I have followed this: [Edge browser crashing after initial watir-webdriver launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31795527/edge-browser-crashing-after-initial-watir-webdriver-launch)
 but no luck. Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a different constructor:

```
IWebDriver wrappedWebDriver = new EdgeDriver(new EdgeOptions());
```

This works for me. No need to specify the folder. Also, think that the normal search patter is the default one.