# "Unknown command received" errors using MicrosoftWebDriver and Selenium (C#)

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge

I am using Selenium (v2.47) and the Microsoft Web Driver (v10.0.10240.0). I am working with some existing C# code that already runs fine on Firefox, IE and Chrome and I want to use it to test the new Edge browser on Windows 10. My code is able to successfully open the browser and navigate to my login page. However I get an "Unknown command received" exception when I do a few basic things such as:

1) maximize the browser

2) call .FindElement(by) on an existing IWebElement.

For example:

driver.Manage().Window.Maximize();  //throws exception

...

IWebElement parent = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));  //works

...

parent.FindElement(by);  //throws exception

Has anyone seen either of these work with Selenium and C# for the Edge browser? Maybe I am doing something wrong here. Or does "Unknown command received" just mean it is unimplemented functionality that will come in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a fair amount of missing functionality in the initial (10.0.10240) Edge driver release, including missing support for `IWebElement.FindElement()`. Subsequent releases, which also required an update to Edge itself via Windows 10 updates, and until very recently only available via so-called Insider builds. A full accounting of what was implemented and when is provided by Microsoft at their [WebDriver implementation status page](https://dev.windows.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/status/webdriver/details/).

Comment: Thanks. From the link I see the insider build is 10547, so I'll try getting that and seeing if any of these work there.

Comment: First I tried using the updated driver (v1.1) and Maximize() worked but IWebElement.FindElement() still did not. I then updated Windows (now at Version1511, build 10586.3) and now not even Driver.FindElement() works for me. So, this combination of web driver and OS version definitely seems to have issues. I'm sure I'll see an update to the driver soon.