# Selenium - Java : Microsoft Edge automation browser (Windows 10)

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I'm facing the next situation: I need to run automation with Selenium Webdriver in Microsoft Edge.

I have installed on Windows

```
Microsoft Edge 44.18362.1.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 18.18362
```

From the next page, I don't see where is the Edge 18 for downloading, neither the 44 version.

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/

Can anybody guide me?
I don't know exactly which is the right version for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) versions 18 and 19 is a Windows Feature on Demand which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver. To get started you will have to enable Developer Mode:

Go to Settings > Update and Security > For Developer and then select “Developer mode”.

For Microsoft Edge (EdgeHTML) builds prior to 18, install a previous release of WebDriver:

**You can also install a standalone version of WebDriver in one of two ways:**

(1) Search “Manage optional features” from Start, then select “Add a Feature,” “WebDriver.”

(2) Install via DISM by running the following command in an elevated command prompt as an administrator:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

References:

(1) [Microsoft WebDriver](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)

(2) [Is there a Selenium WebDriver available for the Microsoft Edge browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30044912/is-there-a-selenium-webdriver-available-for-the-microsoft-edge-browser)

Below link can be helpful for referencing the web driver in your JAVA project.

(3) [bonigarcia/webdrivermanager](https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager)

Comment: The second point of your post, Deepak-MSFT was the solution: DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
Thanks a lot!!!